# jQuery TypeError undefined with setSelectionRange

Tags: jquery, html

I am attempting to focus on a text area after any text. This works in IE and Chrome but in firefox it starts before the text.

What is the cause of the following error:

```
TypeError: $(...)[0] is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

$(focus)[0].setSelectionRange($(focus).val().length, $(focus).val().length);
```

Relevant code:

```
$(focus)[0].setSelectionRange($(focus).val().length, $(focus).val().length);
$(focus).focus();
```

Whole jQuery code:

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.cookie/1.3/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#state").change(function () {
    this.form.submit();
})
var focus = $.cookie("inputFocus");

$(focus)[0].setSelectionRange($(focus).val().length, $(focus).val().length);
$(focus).focus();

$("#supplier_name").val($("#supplier_name").val());
$("#aircraft_type").val($("#aircraft_type").val());
var typingTimer;                
var doneTypingInterval = 600;  

$('#supplier_name').keyup(function(){
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    if ($('#supplier_name').val) {
        typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
    }
    $.cookie("inputFocus", "#supplier_name"); 
});

$('#aircraft_type').keyup(function(){
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    if ($('#aircraft_type').val) {
        typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
    }
    $.cookie("inputFocus", "#aircraft_type"); });
function GetQueryStringParams(sParam)
{
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++)
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam)
        {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}

var state = GetQueryStringParams('state');
var supplier_name = GetQueryStringParams('supplier_name');
var aircraft_type = GetQueryStringParams('aircraft_type');

    if(supplier_name === "" && state === "any" && aircraft_type === "") {
            $('#clear').attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
    $("#clear").click(function() {
    if(state === "any") {
        $("#aircraft_type").val("");
        $("#supplier_name").val("");
    } else {
        $('#state option:selected').remove();
        $("#aircraft_type").val("");
        $("#supplier_name").val("");    
    }
    });

function doneTyping () {
    $("form").submit();
}

});
</script>
```

Comment: The cookie may not be set yet

Comment: shoudn't it be if(...val()), with the paranthesis. besides that try $(focus)[0].selectionStart = $(focus)[0].selectionEnd = $(focus).val().length;

Comment: What do you mean it should be "if(...val())"? I have tried your code and it spits out the following error:



TypeError: $(...).val(...) is undefined
[Break On This Error]  

$(focus)[0].selectionStart = $(focus)[0].selectionEnd = $(focus).val().length;

Comment: with jquery, try this also https://gist.github.com/1007907

Comment: Hi sephit, didnt try it. just overread caret thingy which i had yesterday. i think in that way alexander is right. what returns $.cookie if no value is set?  if(!focus) focus = "";

Answer (score 0):

In more detail.

If the cookie you try to read is non existent $.cookie will return undefined.
As statet in the Docs und "read Cookies"

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

```
$.cookie('not_existing'); // => undefined
```

catch it with

```
if(!focus) focus = "";
```